# cosh x inequality

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

While reading an article on Hoeffding's Inequality, I came across a curious inequality. Namely

$$\cosh x \leq e^{x^2/2} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I tried many ways to prove it and finally, the Taylor series approach worked:

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots$$
$$e^{-x} = 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \cdots$$
 Adding the two and dividing by 2 (This operation being justified as both series converge),
we get

$$\cosh x  = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots$$

Expanding $e^{x^2/2}$ yields

$$e^{x^2/2}  = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^4}{4\times 2!} + \cdots$$

If you do a term by term comparison, you get the desired result.

My question is: Is there another more "Cute"/elegant way to get this result? If so, what is it? I tried using Jensen's Inequality but that didn't help. Also I searched for this inequality using the keywords "cosh x" and "inequality", but didn't get it.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you find this beautiful inequality?

Comment: This was a long time ago, so I actually forgot where I got it from. No doubt from some good probability book. If I find the source, I will update the article.

Comment: The inequality is in Achim Klenke's "Probability theory" (Exercise 9.2.4), but without proof.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The infinite product representation 
of the hyperbolic cosine function gives
$$\cosh(x)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+{4x^2\over \pi^2(2k-1)^2}\right)
\leq \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty {4x^2\over \pi^2(2k-1)^2}\right)
= \exp(x^2/2).$$

Comment: These infinite product representations of functions are handy just like Taylor series.

Comment: Yes, I agree! It's natural for me to think of "products" when trying to bound an exponential. Though, I think Maisam's solution is  better and more direct.

Comment: I was unaware of such an expansion. It's pretty cute and useful. I'll wait for a few more days to see if someone posts something better.

Comment: How do you find the infinite product representation?

Answer (score 19):

Hint: the wanted inequality is equivalent to $\ln(\cosh x) \leq \ln(e^{x^2/2}) $ which is in turn equivalent to  $$\ln(\cosh x) \leq  {x^2/2}.$$ Now define this function $f(x)=\ln(\cosh x) - {x^2/2}$ and $f'(x)=\tanh(x)-x$ and find maximum of $f$.

Comment: This had also occurred to me(later), owing to the fact that all functions are differentiable. I don't suppose a Jensen inequality like proof is possible.

Answer (score 9):

Noticing that $\frac{d}{dx}\tanh x = 1 -\tanh^2x$, note that:

- $1-\tanh^2 u\le1\implies\int_0^t(1-\tanh^2 u)du\le\int_0^tdu\implies\tanh t \le t$
- $\int_0^x \tanh t dt\le\int_0^xtdt\implies\log\cosh x \le \frac{1}{2}x^2\implies\cosh x\le e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting the alternating series for $\log\cosh(x)$:

$$
\log\cosh(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{12} + \frac{x^6}{45} + \mathcal{O}(x^8)
$$

Since the series is alternating you have the inequalities:

$$\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{12} \le \log\cosh(x) \le \frac{x^2}{2}$$

Hence

$$
e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{12}} \le \cosh(x) \le e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}
$$

Keeping more and more terms of the series you can get increasingly tighter inequalities.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688080/closed-form-maclaurin-series-of-log-coshx/4688115