# A bound (dominated function) for $\cosh^2\left(t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, convex-analysis

I would like to bound $$\cosh^2\left(t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}\right)$$  for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, where $\gamma^2\leq1$.
 How can I do such thing?

This inequality maybe useful [cosh x inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331367/cosh-x-inequality)

Comment: This function is unbounded over $\mathbb{R}$. Are you looking for for a dominated function?

Comment: Oh yes it's really good if we can find such function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may write
$$
\cosh^2\left(t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}\right)=\left(\frac{e^{t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}}+e^{-t \sqrt{1-\gamma^2}}}2\right)^2\leq \color{blue}{e^{2|t|\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}}},\quad t \in \mathbb{R},
$$ or
$$
\cosh^2\left(t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}\right)=\frac{e^{2t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}}}4+\frac{e^{-2t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}}}4+\frac12\leq \color{blue}{\frac{e^{2|t|\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}}}4+\frac34},\quad t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Why can we get the second $\leq$ ? How can we have $3/4$?

Comment: If $u\leq0$ then $e^u\leq1$. Thus $\frac{e^{-2t\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}}}4+1\leq \frac14+1=\frac34$, if $t\geq0$.

Comment: You are welcome.