# $\dfrac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2} \leq e^{ \frac{t^2}{2} } $

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, convexity-inequality

We want to prove that $ \forall t, \dfrac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2} \leq e^{ \frac{t^2}{2}  } $

---

I thought to a convexity inequality. If $\psi$ is convex,
$\dfrac{ \psi(a)+\psi(b) }{2} \leq \psi( \frac{ a+b }{2}  )$ or it may be the arithmetic-geometric inequality.

Comment: Duplicates found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdfrac%7Be%5Et%20%2B%20e%5E%7B-t%7D%7D%7B2%7D%20%5Cleq%20e%5E%7B%20%5Cfrac%7Bt%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%20%20%7D%24)

Comment: The Maclaurin expansion might be of help

Comment: Look here also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331367/cosh-x-inequality

Comment: ok, thanks so much.